# Mac cannot copy because file is in use

Tags: macos, copy, ntfs

I have a external hard drive with NTFS format, I used my Mac to copied zip file in to there with size is about 23Gb.

However, when I bring it back to Mac, when transfer almost complete, the message alert with content: "cannot copy because file is in use", then copy process cancel.

Although I already installed paragon NTFS but still get that message.

I also try to copy using terminal by following command: `cp -r /Volumn/source /destination`.

Please help me solve this. The data on zip file is very important to me. Thanks

Comment: this is more of a superuser thing. http://superuser.com

Comment: [try using "`ditto`" on the command line](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html) and maybe you'll have better luck.

Comment: I really scare when using command line, I'm not an IT expert, one mistake may cause data lost.